# Sharepoint List capped registration and infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to create a registration list that is capped at 25 attendees. The way I've done it is creating a list that has already has 25 titles and I used a validation rule =Created<2014/10/21 so that no more can be added.

I would like people to register themselves using an infopath form (they're not very good at SharePoint) Is it possible to do it so that the title is static, jumps to the next one every time someone enter their email address?

I am open to learning code but if it's something that can be done out of the box, that would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance!